# Javascript: erroneous data being set to a map

Tags: javascript, json

I have this function. The input to the function is data obtained from a json file. I have a map called arrowMap which is then set to arrowsMap which is in turn set to arrowsDataMap. The problem is face is that the data is overwritten in the arrowsDataMap at the old keys. So when I do this arrowsDataMap.get("0").get(0).get(1)), i get the data that was at (arrowsDataMap.get("1").get(0).get(1)) and the same data at that location too. So data is essentially overwritten. Any help is appreciated.

```
function animateLines(data) {
pointLength = data.points.length;
arrowLength = data.points["0"].point.length;

var viewEntryKey=0;
for (var viewEntryKey in data.points) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.points[viewEntryKey].point.length; i++) {
        var arrowMap = new Map();

        arrowMap.set(1,data.points[viewEntryKey].point[i].latLng);
        arrowMap.set(2,data.points[viewEntryKey].point[i].size);
        arrowMap.set(3,data.points[viewEntryKey].point[i].angle);

        arrowsMap.set(i,arrowMap);
            //alert(arrowsMap.get(0).get(1));

}

arrowsDataMap.set(viewEntryKey,arrowsMap);
}



json file:

{
  "points": [
  {
    "point": [
      {
        "latLng": [-88.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "0.79"
      },
      {
        "latLng": [-88.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "0.69"
      }
      ,
      {
        "latLng": [-88.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "0.49"
      }
      ,
      {
        "latLng": [-88.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "0.29"
      }
      ,
      {
        "latLng": [-88.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "0.09"
      }
      ,
      {
        "latLng": [-88.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "-0.09"
      }
      ,
      {
        "latLng": [-88.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "-0.29"
      }
      ,
      {
        "latLng": [-88.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "-0.49"
      }
      ,
      {
        "latLng": [-88.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "-0.69"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "point": [
      {
        "latLng": [-89.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "0.79"
      },
      {
        "latLng": [-89.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "0.69"
      }
      ,
      {
        "latLng": [-89.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "0.49"
      }
      ,
      {
        "latLng": [-89.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "0.29"
      }
      ,
      {
        "latLng": [-89.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "0.09"
      }
      ,
      {
        "latLng": [-89.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "-0.09"
      }
      ,
      {
        "latLng": [-89.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "-0.29"
      }
      ,
      {
        "latLng": [-89.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "-0.49"
      }
      ,
      {
        "latLng": [-89.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "-0.69"
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Where is arrowsMap created? I have a feeling that should be recreated for each member of `data.points`. So, inside the first loop, before the second loop starts, put `var arrowsMap = new Map();`, or something similar.

Comment: I created it outside the function with arrowsDataMap. I tried the solution you suggested and it worked! Thank you so much @forgivenson

Comment: You are welcome! I put it as an answer so you can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling you should recreat `arrowsMap` for each member of `data.points`. So, inside the first loop, before the second loop starts, put `var arrowsMap = new Map();`.

Since you weren't creating a new `Map` for each arrow, the data from the previous arrow that was saved was being overwritten by the next arrow.